# Communication between Google App Engine and Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I currently have a ReactJS frontend deployed as a service on Google App Engine (GAE), while my Flask backend API service is deployed on Google Cloud Run.

I made these choices to stay in the free tier while having reasonable limits. As my project was in a test phase, I had just been using the Cloud Run URL to make all my requests from the frontend. However, it is now time for me to make my Cloud Run API instance private and only let requests from my frontend in GAE be served.

I tried some Cloud Run Invoker permissions on the appspot service account but I was unable to make it work. I keep getting 403 forbidden errors on my frontend. I am unsure on how to proceed, as there is no documentation available on connecting GAE and Cloud Run.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but I'm curious - are you saying that if you implement the same cloud run code in GAE, you run the risk of going against the free tier in GAE?

Comment: Yes I think so. I need 1GB and if I use a B4 instance, that would mean I'd have just 4.5 hours compute per day. My app is quite interactive and engagement may be longer than that. Tell me if I'm interpreting the instance hours for GAE incorrectly

Comment: 1GB of memory or what? Also, which version of GAE are you using - Standard or Flex? And when you mean your front end is deployed to GAE, do you mean you essentially have a static site hosted on GAE and all requests to the backend are done via Javascript or maybe PHP and will go to the url you have on Cloud Run?

Comment: Your question needs a lot more details. You question mentions **App Engine -> Cloud Run**. Show other code that generates an error. Show the exact error. Details will help you get a solution.

Comment: The latest comment of @NoCommandLine reach the key point of the question: Does the frontend that call the backend? Or does the fronted serve static file interpreted and ran in your browser, and you browser (the static website) perform the calls to the backend? The deep understanding of the architecture and the communication flow is critical to answer your question!

Comment: @NoCommandLine and guillaume blaquiere You both have got it correct, and yes it is 1GB of memory, I missed that part somehow. It is a static website I think so essentially the browser is making the calls to the backend URL through JavaScript fetch. John Hanley it's a fetch call to the backend URL that causes a forbidden 403 error.

Comment: @NoCommandLine I'm using standard automatic scaling in a F1 instance for the frontend. The static website part I'm not completely sure. As I said, I think it is static, because I'm uploading the react build files to GAE.

Comment: As @John Hanley mentioned above, provide more details like code and the error to get a solution.

Comment: @Akshansha Singhal the code is not the problem here. I'm using fetch to make requests to the Cloud Run URL which is the backend. The frontend is deployed with static build files in GAE. The fetch is returning a 403 Forbidden error because I made the Cloud Run service into authetication mode only. I am just unable to figure out the IAM to like the GAE service account with Cloud Run permissions in some way. According to what others mentioned, it seems to be because it's the browser making the fetch request and not GAE itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) talks about generating a static website. You’ve said that you were connecting from App Engine to Cloud Run, but it seems that you are hosting your static site on App Engine. The connection then will not be from App Engine, but instead it will come from the end user's browser.

You need to remove the access restriction on your Cloud Run service. This is designed for service-to-service authentication, and is not suitable for end user authentication, especially for a public site or one with a large number of users.

There is another product called [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), which might help you with this situation.

Comment: The problem is I cannot set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a ReactJS environment (as all env vars need to start with REACT_APP). Regardless, putting the service account in an environment variable or in a JSON file in the frontend will just expose it to anyone looking at the developer console, so I don't see how this would be a good solution?

Comment: Hey, let us know which App Engine runtime and HTTP client library do you prefer?

Comment: App Engine F1 instance (flex is not enabled). Http client I'm currently just using fetch, but I don't have a preference, if using something else makes it easier, I'm down to explore it.

Comment: The document [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) talks about generating a static website. You’ve said that you were connecting from App Engine to Cloud Run, but it seems that you are hosting your static site on App Engine. The connection then will not be from App Engine, but instead it will come from the end user's browser.

Comment: You need to remove the access restriction on your Cloud Run service. This is designed for service-to-service authentication, and is not suitable for end user authentication, especially for a public site or one with a large number of users.
There is another product called [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), which might help you with this situation.

Comment: I see, that's what I feared. Thanks for taking the time answering my questions. I'll take a look at Firebase auth

Comment: I've updated my answer. And if it helped you, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

From your description of front end static pages calling Cloud Run directly. There are 2 key flags in Cloud Run that will apply here
`--ingress=` - if you specified `internal` or `internal-and-cloud-load-balancing` it will never work
`--no-allow-unauthenticated` - if you specified this, every user will need to be granted their own access and provide their own bearer token
It is a much better design to just use App Engine the way it was intended, and use the back end of App Engine directly